# Getting the id of a switch once that switch is pressed, programmatically, in Kivy

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

[image: screen image of switches and labels]My method set_name_args() is supposed to take a tap on a switch and extract the switch's id. From there, the text of a corresponding label will be appended to the names list.

in Class MainScreen(Screen):

```
def set_name_args(self, instance):
    names=[]
    id=instance #Get the id from instance. Does not currently work.
    extract_num=re.findall(r'\d+', str(id)) #extracts the numerical portion of the switch id
    exp = "self.manager.ids.NewStory.ids.box.ids.switch_label" +str(extract_num)
    names.append(eval(exp).text) #appends the text of MDLabel
    return names
```

and, for further context (also in class MainScreen):

```
    def get_characters_for_story(self, btn):
        x = 0
        self.count = len(dm.return_all_python_dict())
        lst = dm.return_all_python_dict()

        if btn.text == '[size=25]Create Story[/size]':

            while x < self.count:
                name = str(lst[x]["first_name"]) + " " + str(lst[x]["last_name"])
                switch = MDSwitch()
                mdlabel = MDLabel(text=name, font_size=25)
                self.manager.ids.NewStory.ids.box.add_widget(switch)
                #creates switch ids
                self.manager.ids.NewStory.ids.box.ids["switch" + str(x)] = weakref.ref(switch)

                self.manager.ids.NewStory.ids.box.add_widget(
                    mdlabel)
                #creates MDLabel ids
                self.manager.ids.NewStory.ids.box.ids["switch_label"+str(x)] = weakref.ref(mdlabel)
                switch.bind(on_press=self.set_name_args) #bind the problematic function
                x += 1
            if x >= 1:
                self.first_btn_press = False
```

How can I get the text from switch_label0 once switch0 is pressed and so on?

Comment: instance == id (in your example object == id). In python code you cant set/get/change id

Comment: @Neizvestnyj if  I can't get id in python, how else may I get/return the label text when I flip the switch next to the label?

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) addressing your main problem.